# Display HTML 5 Validation message via Program

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I would like to display the html 5 validation message manually (i.e. via code). According to my understanding, there is no direct way to invoke this message. However, we can bring it via submit button click.

I tried to bring the validation message (if the field is invalid) when you click on the html body:

```
// if url is invalid, display the error message.
if(!$('#theurl')[0].checkValidity()){

    console.log('Button Click');
    $('#btn').click();

}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knvn/wLCdz/1/) for the same. Unfortunately, the above code is getting crashed. I have no idea why. Instead, if you click on the fake button manually it works fine.

Please help me to accomplish this.

Comment: Why don't you right you own validation?

Comment: Well, I can do that but I prefer to take the advantage of native API at the moment. Also, now I'm bit curious about the reason for browser crash (an unexpected infinite loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your Click function is taking the parameter 'e', but you're looking for the parameter "event".

```
$('body').click(function(e){
```

The call

```
    $(event.target)
```

Change it to 'e.target' and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLCdz/3/

Also, the `checkValidity` function is called from the form, not from the individual items within the form.  So, if you call the checkValidity function like this:

```
document.forms[0].checkValidity()
```

it will stop crashing for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle, the code on line 22 is causing an infinite loop, which ends up causing the script to crash:

```
$('#btn').click();
```

If you comment out that line it no longer crashes. Triggering a click on the button like you are doing is also causing another click to be triggered on the body element.

To see what I mean, comment that line out, put a bad url in the form and click on the body. Each click writes a message to the console.

Comment: Ya, I am aware that the browser is crashing because of an infinite loop (see my comments on the question) but I was not sure why. I am returning from the handler if the clicked element is button.

Comment: I think @Richard's answer is what you want

Comment: Well, the issue is solved now. I was using the wrong parameter(i.e. `event` instead if `e`). Thanks anyway you are right at your point :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<form id="formId">
...
</form>

$('body').click(function(e){

    // ignore, if clicked on the url
    if ($(event.target).closest('#theurl').length) {
        return;
    }

    // ignore, if clicked on the email
    if ($(event.target).closest('#theemail').length) {
        return;
    }

    // ignore, if clicked on the button
    if ($(event.target).closest('#btn').length) {
        return;
    }

    // if url is invalid, display the error message.
    if(!$('#formId')[0].theurl.checkValidity()){

        console.log('Button Click');
        $('#btn').click();

    }

});
```

Comment: why are you downvoting to me? I suggest to call checkValidity function  from the form and not from individual items.